# jquery append() method on empty XML element

Tags: jquery, xml, dom

This could just be a syntax error, but I'm trying to create a Document object from scratch, starting with `document.implementation.createDocument()` and then using jquery's `append()` method to add the elements. But it's not appending:

```
var myDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", 'stuff', null);

$("stuff",myDoc).attr("test","tested");

$("stuff",myDoc).append("<test>A</test>");
$("<test>B</test>").appendTo("stuff",soapEnv);

var s = new XMLSerializer();
alert(s.serializeToString(soapEnv));
```

This should output:

```
<stuff test="tested">
    <test>A</test>
    <test>B</test>
</stuff>
```

But instead it outputs:

```
<stuff test="tested" />
```

So the selector seems to be working, just not the method. My only guess is the method doesn't account for the fact that elements are empty (`<stuff />`) until they have children. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't construct a non-HTML node using jquery. This means `$('<test>X</test>')` isn't going to work, but `$('<span>X</span>')` will. (You can use jQuery to read an XML document, and look for things like `$('test')`, but constructing them is another matter.) This is due to how jQuery creates these elements internally.

**EDIT**

Here is the documentation supporting my claim: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

> A string of HTML to create on the fly.
>   Note that this parses HTML, not  XML.

Comment: P.S., one more note/edit:  I believe you actually _can_ get this work in one of the browsers out there (I don't recall which), just not all.